# bootstrap 3 noConflict mode for popover conflicts with itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am in the process of changing one of our legacy apps from it's old design to using bootstrap and angularjs.

previously we relied heavily on jquery and jquery-ui, so when I included bootstrap and used it to enable popovers in my page, the code conflicted (somehow) with jquery-ui.

to enable bootstrap noConflict, I did:

```
var bsPopover = $.fn.popover.noConflict();
$.fn.bspopover = bsPopover;
```

and called all my popover codes like so:

```
$('#notify-tasks').bspopover({...});
```

this call now works as it should, it no longer conflicts with jquery-ui, but, i get this error in my browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

here is where the code fails:

```
Tooltip.prototype.toggle = function (e) {
  var self = e ? $(e.currentTarget)[this.type](this.getDelegateOptions()).data('bs.' + this.type) : this
```

running through the variables in this line of code, I found out that:

```
this.type = "popover"
```

and since what $(e.currentTarget)[this.type] is really trying to do is call $(element)["popover"], it obviously fails, since popover is now defined as bspopover.

Am I missing out on something when enabling noConflict for Bootstrap?